# Parsing a date form a string of form YYYY-MM-DD in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a way in Haskell to parse a date from a string of format "YYYY-MM-DD"? That is, something like `parseDateFromString 2016-10-20` that would then return a date in some commonly used Haskell date format.

Answer (score 5):

[`Data.Time`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.6.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Format.html) provides `parseTimeM`, which is a bit unwieldy. I might be overlooking a simpler alternative.

```
> import Data.Time
> parseTimeM False defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d" "2016-10-20" :: Maybe UniversalTime
Just 2016-10-20 00:00:00
```

The return type is fairly open. You can return the value to any monad; `Maybe` seemed like a good example to reflect an answer or a failure to parse the string. The type wrapped by `Maybe` is any instance of the `ParseTime` typeclass; `UniversalTime` is defined in the library.